# output not produced in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to find the average for each widget using mapreduce. The job gets completed successfully but no out is produced when using hadoop fs -cat user/vagrant/example-1/part-r-00000

```
    public static class MaxWidgetReducer
  extends Reducer<Text, FloatWritable, FloatWritable, NullWritable> {

public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<FloatWritable> vals, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  Float totalPrice = 0.0f;
  Float avgPrice = 0.0f;
  Integer count = null;

  for (FloatWritable w : vals) {

      totalPrice = (totalPrice + w.get());
        count++;
```

}

```
  avgPrice = (totalPrice)/(count);

  context.write(new FloatWritable(avgPrice), NullWritable.get());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you use a try/catch block in both: mapper and reducer, so you could know if it is due to an exception being thrown when processing your data, try to cast w.get() to float in order to be able to add that value to the total price.

Cheers.